# Create a nested dictionary with multipe dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple dictionaries with different data for each country as a key:

```
countries = {'Portugal', 'US'}
score = {'Portugal': 88.0, 'US': 86.20}
year = {'Portugal': 2014, 'US': 2013 }
price ={'Portugal': 26.77, 'US': 36.58 }
```

I want to create a nested dictionary with country as a key and inside add key value pairs for each countries data in each dict.

I make two dictionaries with countries as the keys, and the keys for each dictionary

```
dd = {key: None for key in countries}
d_temp = dict.fromkeys(["Variety","Year","Price","Points","Adjective"])

for c in countries:
    d_temp['Variety'] = d1[c]
    d_temp['Year'] = d2[c]
    d_temp['Price'] = d3[c]
    d_temp['Points'] = d4[c]
    d_temp['Adjective'] = d5[c]
    dd[c] = d_temp
```

But after each iteration it updates every value for each previous country

Comment: what is the desired result?

Comment: Move d_temp = dict.fromkeys(...) inside the loop. You're assigning the same instance of d_temp to each key. All the keys point at the same instance. Thus when you update it for one, you change them all. Instead create a new d_temp inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

This will deliver `{'Portugal': {'Variety': 88.0, 'Year': 2014, 'Price': 26.77}, 'US': {'Variety': 86.2, 'Year': 2013, 'Price': 36.58}}`

```
countries = {'Portugal', 'US'}
score = {'Portugal': 88.0, 'US': 86.20}
year = {'Portugal': 2014, 'US': 2013}
price = {'Portugal': 26.77, 'US': 36.58}

dd = {key: None for key in countries}

for c in countries:
    d_temp = {}

    d_temp['Variety'] = score[c]
    d_temp['Year'] = year[c]
    d_temp['Price'] = price[c]
    dd[c] = d_temp

print(dd)
```

Your problem is that you are creating a reference to the same dictionary (d_temp) on every country key. This means every country shares the same nested dictionary (d_temp). That´s what you see as "updating" of the country sub-dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension:

```py
countries = {'Portugal', 'US'}
score = {'Portugal': 88.0, 'US': 86.20}
year = {'Portugal': 2014, 'US': 2013}
price = {'Portugal': 26.77, 'US': 36.58}

key_to_dict = {'score': score, 'year': year, 'price': price}

output = {country: {k: d[country] for k, d in key_to_dict.items()} for country in countries}

print(output)
# {'US': {'score': 86.2, 'year': 2013, 'price': 36.58}, 'Portugal': {'score': 88.0, 'year': 2014, 'price': 26.77}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think that using [dictionary comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-dict_comprehension) is the best way to to solve this problem — but think it can be done in a more readable and flexible manner, like so:

```
countries = {'Portugal', 'US'}
score = {'Portugal': 88.0, 'US': 86.20}
year = {'Portugal': 2014, 'US': 2013}
price = {'Portugal': 26.77, 'US': 36.58}

# Map variable names to corresponding data dictionaries.
dicts = {name: globals()[name] for name in ("score", "year", "price")}

# Pull data out for each country.
dd = {country:
        {name: data[country] for name, data in dicts.items()}
            for country in countries}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dd, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
{'Portugal': {'score': 88.0, 'year': 2014, 'price': 26.77},
 'US': {'score': 86.2, 'year': 2013, 'price': 36.58}}
```